# ls -l and grep is not working together

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, grep

I am trying to get list of files which starts with fs and at first

I used that command

```
ls -l /etc/ | grep ^fs
```

0 Results

then I used that one

```
ls /etc/ | grep ^fs
```

Got results.

I wonder why I can't get any results with "-l"

Cheers!

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the output of `ls -l`.  Notice that it doesn't start with the filename!

```
$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 cnorum domain users 10338 Sep 16 15:43 file1
drwxr-xr-x 20 cnorum domain users  4096 Sep 26 09:20 dir1
drwxr-xr-x  2 cnorum domain users  4096 Sep 25 14:00 dir2
drwxr-xr-x  2 cnorum domain users  4096 Jul 18 09:56 dir3
```

You don't need grep at all - why not just:

```
ls -l /etc/fs*
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder why I can't get any results with "-l"

coz u send to grep line by line

look at this:

```
ls -l /etc | grep ^dr
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that you are using the beggining of line character in the expression (^), as with -l the line doesn't start with filename